# Android billing - Testing purchases with android.test.purchased in production/alpha/beta

Tags: java, android, testing, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm using Google Play billing API (v3) and I'm testing in-app purchases with `sku=android.test.purchased`. To do this, I have modified the method `Security.verifyPurchase` from the helper classes like this:

```
public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey, String signedData, String signature, String sku) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(signedData) || TextUtils.isEmpty(base64PublicKey) || TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Purchase verification failed: missing data.");
        if ("android.test.purchased".equals(sku) || BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.e(TAG, "This was a test purchase");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64PublicKey);
    return Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);
}
```

My code is a little different from the that in the tutorials I've found: I added this:

```
"android.test.purchased".equals(sku)
```

Initially, only the verification for `BuildConfig.DEBUG` was added, but I needed to give testing users the possibility to buy products quickly, without adding their payment data.

My question is: is there a big security problem if I'll use this code in my production app (or is it OK just for alpha / beta)?

Answer (score 2):

This modification is definitely not OK for production version because it disables response verification. If an attacker provides no `base64PublicKey`, `signedData`, `signature` and the test `sku` you have in your code, then your app will allow to use in-app features in production without actually paying for them.

If in DEBUG version you want to allow all `sku's`, just remove your check. If you want to allow your `sku` only, use `&&` operator or the code below.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Log.e(TAG, "This was a test purchase");
    return "android.test.purchased".equals(sku);
}
```

Comment: So you are actually saying that I shouldn't test at all with android.test.purchased in production mode (where. BuildConfig.DEBUG == false)?

Comment: If DEBUG == false this is still not a production code because all other parameters are empty. In real production code they must be filled. So, if you want to test sku in production, have to test all other parameters as well.